# Saving a jmeter log output as multiple file types at once

Tags: jmeter

I'm running jmeter on a continuous integration platform from a repository and I need to generate both an xml .jtl file and csv .jtl file. Right now I am using -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml and a simple data writer writing to a csv file, but the csv file ends up not being formatted very well and same http calls on load tests don't get combined. If I could create log files for both that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re doing looks correct to me.
What do you mean by csv not being formatted correctly ?

You could invert it by keeping output as csv and add a View Results Tree with filename set and in configure button, ensure you check all fields you need.

Of course, do this only in Non Gui mode.